# reset_index not resetting index after double groupby

Tags: python, pandas

When I use pandas groupby to sum a value by groups and use the result in another groupby to calculate the % of the group total within each subgroup, I am unable to reset index to access the columns by slicing. How can I access the columns or reset the index?

```py
test = pd.DataFrame({'Animal' : ['Falcon', 'Falcon','Parrot', 'Parrot','Mouse','Mouse'],'Type':['Bird', 'Bird', 'Bird', 'Bird', 'Rodent','Rodent'],'Count' : [380., 370., 24., 26., 1.9, 2.8]})

# second groupby gives a proportion of total animal counts within each type
gb = test.groupby(['Type','Animal']).sum().groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x: x / float(x.sum()))
```

When I unstack, I'm unable to reset the index so that I can extract the columns

```py
gb = gb.unstack().reset_index()
gb.loc['Animal']
```

results in an error that indicates there is no column named 'Animal'.

How can I reset after unstacking so that I can subset columns (or rename them, which would be an okay substitute right now)?

- edit example df to more clearly illustrate the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have misread the error. The error was that 'Animal' could not be found in the index, not the columns. The confusion here arises because of how .loc works. If only one item is passed to .loc this will be interpreted as an index. Only the second item is for the columns. So you could use:

```
gb.loc[:, 'Animal']
```

But you can also simply do:

```
gb['Animal']
```

Answer (score 1):

> When I unstack, I'm unable to reset the index so that I can extract the columns
>
> ```
> gb.unstack()
> gb.loc['Animal']
> ```

You can get the 'Animal' column this way:
`gb.loc[:,'Animal']`
Or
`gb['Animal']`

Answer (score 0):

What do you what to calculate?

I think the second `groupby` operation is out of place:

```
gb = test.groupby('Animal').sum().groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x: x / float(x.sum()))
```

Try this:

```
gb = test.groupby("Animal").sum().apply(lambda x: x / float(x.sum())).reset_index()
```